# Proper way to test threshold-based grouping of data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I have a population data.
I observe two clusters in the distribution of one continuous variable from this population.

I can easily group my data into two clusters with a threshold on this variable.

I also have a hypothesis about these two clusters such that I expect another variable X to be significantly different between two clusters.
That’s indeed the case when I test it. However, I’m now confused whether I should also test the initial clustering step.
For example, maybe, I’m just lucky with my clustering and even two randomly selected subsets of data would be different in X.
Do I need to do another test for this or significant difference of X between the groups are already doing it?